# A word meaning not to change the meaning of something

Tags: single-word-requests

The title is confusing. I hope this explains my question better.

If I'm trying to tell a friend that I enjoyed a talk we had, there are a multitude of ways I can say this. I can say it bluntly, or describe the talk we had with positive words.

The talk we had was good.
The talk we had was great.

With either sentence, my friend could gather that I enjoyed our talk. They used different words, but they both described that I enjoyed our talk. Is there a word to use that would describe this situation in which two different words could be used, but the meaning would stay the same? Am I just overthinking this?

Edit: I think a much better way of explaining my question is with Word : Synonym :: (word I'm wondering about) : sentence

Comment: Overthinking, I would imagine

Comment: Two different words to describe the same thing in the same way are **synonyms**

Comment: _Salva veritate_ is the philosophical term; Latin for 'preserving truth".

Comment: Weather Vane, I definitely could've explained it better. synonym : word (what I'm looking for) : sentence     I'm not sure if that's any better. Salva veritate. I like that.

Comment: I would say 'reworded' or 'rephrased' a sentence. That suggests without loss of meaning too, to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for:

> **paraphrase**:
>
> 1. express the meaning of (something written or spoken) using different words, especially to achieve greater clarity.
> 2. a rewording of something written or spoken.

Alternatives (as suggested in comments), depending on context and connotation: reword, rephrase